# Converting dataframe format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which looks as follows :

```
Type    Availability   Count

DayTime   Cancelled       10
Morning   Cancelled       15
Night     Cancelled       13
DayTime   Trip Completed  14
Morning   Trip Completed  71
Night     Trip Completed  32
DayTime   Not-Present     13
Morning   Not-Present     43
Night     Not-Present     23
```

I want to convert this data frame into a format which will have only 3 rows, namely, DayTime, Morning and Night. And 3 columns, namely, Cancelled, Trip Completed and Not-Present which will have the respective counts. 
How can I do that in R ? Please help.

Comment: Try `xtabs(Count ~ Type + Availability, data = dat)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `tidyr::spread`.

```
my_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Type,    ~Availability,   ~Count,

"DayTime",   "Cancelled",       10,
"Morning",   "Cancelled",       15,
"Night",     "Cancelled",       13,
"DayTime",   "Trip Completed",  14,
"Morning",   "Trip Completed",  71,
"Night",     "Trip Completed",  32,
"DayTime",   "Not-Present",     13,
"Morning",   "Not-Present",     43,
"Night",     "Not-Present",     23
)

my_data %>% tidyr::spread(key = Availability, value = Count)
```

Comment: yes, Figured out that its a simple example of long to wide format.

Comment: yep, you got it